# NetLogo: Finding the average value of a set of turtles

Tags: average, netlogo, agents

I'm trying to implement a monitor in the user interface that displays the average value of a variable shared by a breed of turtles (turtles own). Does anyone know of a method of collecting all the values, adding them together and dividing by the quantity of turtles to get the value or know of an easier method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the variable that each turtle has is `shell-size`, for example, then:

```
print mean [shell-size] of turtles
```

will do it.  It might be useful to know how to do this by hand, so that you can do other calculations if you want.  Here's one way:

```
print (sum [shell-size] of turtles) / (count turtles)
```

Here's another

```
let total 0
ask turtles [set total total + shell-size]
print total / (count turtles)
```

Obviously, you'll want to replace the `print` statements with whatever suits your needs.  For a monitor, you should be able to enter this code directly into the interface, or wrap it up in reporter and then use that in the monitor.